# getSelection() broken in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, getselection

I use the **window.getSelection()** method on my project to make a quotable text

It's working just fine in all modern browsers, exept IE10. In IE10 console returns correct text, but the selection is broken.

The only code I used:

```
text = window.getSelection().toString();
console.log(text);
```

This code calls on **mouseup** event.

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this should work for ie < 9.0

```
var texttest = document.selection.createRange();
alert (texttest.text);
```

this is for all browsers except ie < 9.0

```
var texttest = document.getSelection();
alert(texttest);
```